# How to print an open office document in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I imported cups into python. I can print:

> conn.printFile('EPSON-L350-Series',
>   '/home/pedro/getEmailtexts/stragglers/17BElate', 'test', {})

Trouble is, there is no formatting at all, the first line is right along the top edge of the page and very close to the right edge of the page.

So I copied and pasted into Libre Office, but that won't print.

> > > > conn.printFile('EPSON-L350-Series', '/home/pedro/getEmailtexts/stragglers/17BElate.odt', 'test', {})
> > > >         Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
> > > >         
> > > >             conn.printFile('EPSON-L350-Series', '/home/pedro/getEmailtexts/stragglers/17BElate.odt', 'test', {})
> > > >         cups.IPPError: (1034, 'Unsupported document- format"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text".')
> > > >         (Same error if I try .docx)

Question: Is there a way to print .odt or .docx documents directly using the python cups module? Should I be putting options in the curly brackets??

Comment: Have you considered converting it to pdf, (e.g using "libreoffice --convert-to pdf document.odt") and printing that?

Comment: I have never tried to print from Python. If it is easier to print pdf, I'll go for it! I will have 300+ emails saved as text files, so I would like to "Automate the Boring Stuff" as Al Sweigart put it so nicely!

Comment: Now I'm stuck again: I imported the Python module text2pdf, but I can't find any docs, so I don't know the syntax and my guesses don't work!

Comment: You're not trying to use text2pdf to convert ODF, are you?

Comment: Nope, still want to make cups print a Libre Office .odt file or a .docx file. But I can now convert all text files in bash with: for i in *.txt; do text2pdf -o "$i".pdf "$i"; done, then I can print from Python with cups.